# android get photo path without take photo

Tags: android, path, camera, photo

I would like to get camera photo real path, without taking photo.

What I'm using for now is:

```
String path=""; //The real path I want...
String[] projection=new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN};     
final Cursor c=context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN+" DESC"); 
if(c!=null)
{
  c.moveToFirst();
  path=c.getString(1);
  Log.i(Constants.TAG, "File Path: "+path);
  path=path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
}
```

But the result from above just changed sometime...

For normal case, it will be **/storage/ext_sd/DCIM/100MEDIA/**

(I'm using HTC Butterfly, android 4.1.1, exactly same module called DroidDNA in United Stats)

This afternoon, after I move some of my photo to another folder (operate on phone, not PC)

The result changed to **/storage/ext_sd/[some_other_of_my_image_folder]/**

How can I get camera photo's real path ? Please help me :-(

Edit: I'm trying another way like following:

```
Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Photo path: "+f.getPath());
if(f.exists())
{
  File test1=new File(f, "100MEDIA/");
  if (test1.exists())
  {f=test1;}
  else
  {
    File test2=new File(f, "100ANDRO/");
    if(test2.exists())
    {f=test2;}
    else
    {
      File test3=new File(f, "Camera/");
      if(!test3.exists())
      {test3.mkdirs();}
      f=test3;
    }
  }
}
else
{
  f=new File(f, "Camera/");
  f.mkdirs();
}
```

It returned path like: **/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/**, which is my phone's internal 16GB space.

I had already set my camera photo store to external microSD, which path should be **/ext_sd/DCIM/100MEDIA/**

Really need help, MEDIC !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 people vote up my question, so I guess maybe other programmers are facing same issue.

I got a way to overcome this, and following is my code :

```
String path="";
String[] projection=new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN};     
final Cursor c=context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN+" DESC");
boolean isOK=false; //Found a DCIM path ?
if(c!=null)
{
  c.moveToFirst();
  while(!isOK)
  {
    path=c.getString(1);
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "File Path: "+path);
    path=path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    isOK=!(path.indexOf("DCIM")==-1); //Is thie photo from DCIM folder ?

    c.moveToNext(); //Add this so we don't get an infinite loop if the first image from
                    //the cursor is not from DCIM
  }
}
Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Only Path: "+path);
```

Express :

First, that's my SD card

- /DCIM/100MEDIA/xxx.JPG (photo from camera)
- /Media/image/comics/xman/01.JPG
- ...
- ..
- .
- /Media/image/hot/youknowwhatitis/hot01.JPG

I always read first record from **context.getContentResolver().query**'s cursor.

Normally, it return photos inside DCIM first, and then other photo/image/picture.

One day morning, I move a file from DCIM to another folder, (via android's Gallery APP)

and **context.getContentResolver().query**'s first record changed to other non DCIM content,

bring this issue to me...orz

---

**THIS IS NOT PERFECT solution**, if user didn't take any photos to DCIM, this solution will become useless.

Since I'm developing a multimedia APP, guess user should/must a photo lover...
That's the best way I can do until now, hope it bring  little help to others.

Comment: Excellent solution...surprised this hasn't circulated more.

Comment: However, there is one small bug...you forgot to add c.movetoNext(). Otherwise, if the first picture that the cursor returns is not from DCIM, it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: If I want to load other application's photo, how can I do?

Comment: can you please tell me How can I get the default directory of photo made by camera in android?